# Manage GMail account through Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, thunderbird

For many years I've got a complete mess in my GMail account.

I've decided to organize this account, though I cannot to this, because the default (web) interface and management tools of GMail are useless.
So the first step, was to integrate my GMail account with the Mozilla Thunderbird client.

My question is: If I'll take an action in my Thunderbird client (such as deleting messages from the Inbox folder), it will effect my default GMail account?

If I'll delete message XYZ from Thunderbird, I won't see the message in the default GMail web client? (mail.gmail.com)

Actually?.. I have to say that this question is a bit rhetorical, because it seem that messages won't be deleted from the main Google client, and it's not good for me.

Though new messages (**after** the complete setup and integration of Mozilla Thunderbird with GMail), will be completely deleted from my account.

How can I effect old messages as well?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

**Solved!**
I feel really stupid right now...
Refreshing the Gmail web client page shows me that the inbox is clear of the deleted messages (using TB)
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The only noticeable thing you can't do is manage filters. Thunderbird has it's own client-side filtering, while Gmail's filters are obviously serverside. They don't interact, but remember that the Gmail filters will trigger as soon as the message hits the server, before Thunderbird ever has a chance to see the mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: If I'll take an action in my Thunderbird client (such as deleting messages from the Inbox folder), it will effect my default GMail account?

Yes, if you set up the account with IMAP, both will be synchronized. Your Thunderbird client will display every Gmail label as a folder, thus moving messages in a folder means "applying a label" in Gmail. All changes you make are almost instantaneously visible in the web client too.

> If I'll delete message XYZ from Thunderbird, I won't see the message in the default GMail web client? (mail.gmail.com)

If you delete a message in Thunderbird, it will be moved to a folder you set (preferably the Gmail Trash folder). Because of that you will still be able to see it in the Gmail web client, under "Trash".

In order to completely delete messages, you will have to clean out the GMail trash, of course.

> Though new messages (after the complete setup and integration of Mozilla Thunderbird with GMail), will be completely deleted from my account.

What exactly are you meaning with new messages? Note that there is nothing changing when you use Thunderbird – messages will still land in your inbox.

> How can I effect old messages as well?

What do you mean with "effect"? You will be able to see **all** your messages in the folders once you set up Thunderbird, which means you can always use its search function and batch move/delete messages, et cetera.

For more details about how to set up Thunderbird, see the following pages:

- [Recommended IMAP client settings](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78892#)
- [Thunderbird 3.0 - Gmail help](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=180189)

Comment: Firstly - Thank you very much for your informative answer.
The problem is, that if I'll delete message in TB from the inbox, I'll still be able to see it in the inbox of the Gmail web client. It looks like actions (in TB) will effect only in TB, but only for old messages (old = before the TB setup).

Comment: I forgot to mention - I'm using TB with IMAP settings

Comment: Are you sure the deleted mails go to the GMail Trash folder? Also, are you sure you are deleting all mails of a conversation? Maybe Gmail keeps items in the inbox if there are still some mails of this conversation left.

Comment: I even deleted items from the TB trash folder, and still the items are shown in the inbox folder of Gmail web client
For example: if I'll get message NOW, I'll be able to delete it from TB and it will also effect Gmail web client.

Comment: What happens when you manually move those messages from TB to the "Gmail Trash" folder, instead of deleting them?

Comment: Same same... :/

Comment: **Solved!**
I feel really stupid right now...
Refreshing the Gmail web client page shows me that the inbox is clear of the deleted messages (using TB)
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Oh, perfect! I was just thinking, "Wait, this **has to work**!".

Answer (score 5):

Some additions:

- Deleting a mail from Trash - even using the GMail web interface - **doesn't delete the message completely**. It remains still available in "All mail". AFAIK the "All mail" folder is available as IMAP folder in thunderbird, too.
- Deleting a mail completely requires deleting it from "All mail", too, but that makes also the corresponding entry in contacts disappear. This way, if you want to keep the contacts, you're indirectly forced to keep the messages in "All mail", too. GMail displays a warning message if you try to remove Mails from "All mail", but it seems there is no other way to completely remove mails.

Comment: Good to know, +1 for you. Interestingly, I haven't had these issues in Apple Mail. There, deleting a message moved it to the Gmail Trash and therefore out of "All Mails". Also, according to the Mozilla guides, it's not advisable to actually enable the "All Mail" folder over IMAP as it causes using double the space for the mailbox.

Comment: I don't care if contacts will be deleted.
It's more important for me to be able to delete mails through TB permanently.
Unfortunately, deleting mails from "All Mail" will not work for me as well.
Any other ideas maybe? thanks mate.

Comment: **Solved!**
I feel really stupid right now...
Refreshing the Gmail web client page shows me that the inbox is clear of the deleted messages (using TB)
Thank you very much for your help!